# Rails - possible to share views (partials, templates, and layouts) between namespaced controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to share views including partials, layouts, and templates between controllers from different namespaces.

#### The problem

Instead of putting my views in

```
app/views/#{namespace}/#{controller}/...
app/views/layouts/#{namespace}/...
```

I want to put my views in

```
app/views/#{controller}/... 
app/views/layouts/... # as normal, without namespaces
```

I'd also like this to be optional. For example, if there's a layout in `app/views/layouts/#{namespace}/...` then use it, otherwise use `app/views/layouts/...` as normal.

#### Some things I've tried:

1. Using something like [`prepend_view_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/prepend_view_path) isn't going to work here, because for `admin/courses#index` it's still going to look for a template `admin/courses/index` within whatever the view paths are.
2. Using the [`layout`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout) method might work, but probably not for templates and partials.
3. I've tried overriding the render method, but this seems a little *hacky*. And I can't just do it in the `ApplicationController`, because it doesn't handle rendering partials from within a view. So i'd have to override the render method again in the `ApplicationHelper` class, which is awkward, not DRY, and not as straight-forward.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love rails. It does it automagically, sorta.

I had controllers that were extending from a base controller, i.e. `Admin::CoursesController` was extending `BaseCoursesController`, etc.

So I just needed to put my views in

```
app/views/base_courses/index...
```

And I can still optionally put my views in

```
app/views/admin/courses/index...
```

Voilà!